# Debug method improvement

Tags: php, optimization, laravel, laravel-4, static-libraries

Doing custom debug method, I thought use/create a library but a private function (if agree with me: controller are classes, right?) is a comfortable piece to access/use.

```
<?php
class CartController extends BaseController {
  // is well decalared?
  protected $var;

  public function index() {
    // https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#example
    Cart::instance('shopping')->add('192ao12', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
    Cart::instance('shopping')->add('1239ad0', 'Product 2', 2, 5.95, array('size' => 'large'));
    // want to use $cart
    $cart = Cart::content();
    // comment to continue
    $this->_debug($cart);

    /* code */
  }

  private function _debug($var) {
    $this->var = $var;
    // 'echo' is a little hero, a view? if i can't avoid it i'll do
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($this->var);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
  }
}
```

`$var` full of objects and things, how to manage it without using dozens of `if`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do it in every controllers. You should create a helper function for that. Don't forget to load it on composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": ["app/lib/helpers/debug.php"]
}
```

Comment: How it will be called inside the controller/possible view?

Comment: by doing _debug() instead of $this->_debug()